# Java: Error in focusLost method when extract data from the text field

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, lost-focus

I get this strange error when I try to extract data from a text field on focusLost.

So I have a text-field and the idea is that when user enters data after that clicks somewhere else, the input has to be validated.

this is the line in constructor where I add ficus listener to the text field

```
ip_address_textField.addFocusListener(new ip_address_textField_FieldHandler());
```

inside of this class I have another class

```
public class ip_address_textField_FieldHandler implements FocusListener {

private static final String IPADDRESS_PATTERN =
        "^([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +
        "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +
        "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +
        "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])$";

private Pattern pattern;
private Matcher matcher;

@Override
public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Focus Gained");

}

@Override
public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.out.println(ip_address_textField.getText().trim());
    //ip_address_textField.setText(IPADDRESS_PATTERN);
    System.out.println("Focus Lost ->");
}
```

The JTextField is class variable

The error which I get is:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at mia.recommender.ch02.Course_Recommender$ip_address_textField_FieldHandler.focusLost
```

Comment: Without more info, it's likely you've created a local version of `ip_address_textField` when you created the UI.  In any case, you should look at using `InputVerifier` instead.  Take a look at [Validating Input](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#inputVerification) for more details

Comment: I found it. You are right. The code is so huge(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either of these two is null :

- `ip_address_textField` - While you try to call getText() it throws nullpointer
- `ip_address_textField.getText()` - While you try to trim it throws nullpointer

Comment: its the firs one, I don't know why and how to fix it. I was thinking that it is somehow related to the fact that the FocusListener is attached to the textfield from which I want to extract text...

Comment: remove the trim and try once

Comment: so basically ip_address_textField is null. Do you know where is this initialized?

Comment: in constructor JTextField ip_address_textField = new JTextField(10);
  System.out.println("====>" + ip_address_textField.getText()); This doesn't give error

Comment: @Alex, Read MadProgrammer's comment. You created a "local" variable in the constructor. Get rid of the "JTextField" part of your constructor statement. This will then initialize the instance variable that you can reference in your code. However you should still be using an `InputVerifier`, not a FocusListener for this.

Comment: u need to post the rest of code. Otherwise, I can't comment on the scope of this variable.